# I tried to make list comprehension for leap year identifier code in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried to make list comprehension for leap year identifier code,

```
year =int(input())
["Leap year"*(n%4==0 and (n%100!=0 or n%400==0)) or "Non Leap year"*n for n in year]

error:

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15112/1558939479.py in <module>
          1 year =int(input())
    ----> 2 ["Leap year"*(n%4==0 and (n%100!=0 or n%400==0)) or "Non Leap year"*n for n in year]
    
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

i need your assistance to make this right, Thanks legends! cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension is not needed here:

```
year =int(input())
print("Leap year" if (year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)) else "Non Leap year")
```